# Generators to iterate over a dictionary uniformly in both Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to efficiently iterate over the values/items in a dictionary that works in both Python 2 and Python 3?

In Python 2, I can write

```
for x in mydict:
for x in mydict.iterkeys():
for x in mydict.viewkeys():
for x in mydict.itervalues():
for x in mydict.viewvalues():
for x in mydict.iteritems():
for x in mydict.viewitems():
```

and in Python 3, I have the following possibilities:

```
for x in mydict:
for x in mydict.keys():
for x in mydict.values():
for x in mydict.items():
```

So, I can iterate over the keys with `for x in mydict`, and that works in both Python 2 and 3. But is there a way to iterate over values and key-value pairs (‘items’) that works universally? I need it for writing Python code that can be run in both Python versions.

(On a side note, other obstacles with iterators can be bypassed easily; take for example:

```
if sys.version_info.major<3:
    from itertools import izip as zip, imap as map
```

However, the dictionary methods cannot be redefined easily like `map` and `zip`.)

Any ideas?

Comment: EDIT: I think you mean to say generators to iterate over the dictionary

Answer (score 9, accepted):

values() version of Just another dunce's answer

```
for value in (mydict[key] for key in mydict):
```

or

```
def dict_values(d):
   return (mydict[key] for key in mydict)

def dict_items(d):
   return ((key, mydict[key]) for key in mydict)

for value in dict_values(mydict):
    ...

for value in dict_items(mydict):
    ...
```

This is pretty crappy though. You could check the python version and instead of returning the generator, return `d.items()` or `d.iteritems()` as appropriate

I think a better question may be how to write Python2 code that works well with 2to3 and generates good Python3 code

Comment: I favor gnibbler's proposal of checking the Python version (once, at the beginning of the Python script) and defining functions that return the correct iterator `d.items()` or `d.iteritems()`.

Answer (score 8):

The following code works in both Py2 and Py3:

```
def iteritems(d):
    'Factor-out Py2-to-3 differences in dictionary item iterator methods'
    try:
         return d.iteritems()
    except AttributeError:
         return d.items()

d = dict(red=1, blue=2, green=3)
for k, v in iteritems(d):
    print(k)
    print(v)
    print('')
```

Note, this solution has the advantage of using the native iterators rather than rolling your own generators and doing your own lookups.  The native iterators are faster than the other solutions presented.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you a generator:

```
for key,value in ((key,mydict[key] for key in mydict)
```

If you want a list, use [] around the expression instead of the () on the outside

Comment: An easier way would be to use mydict.iteritems()

Comment: What you have in the post would work in both 2 and 3 but `.iteritems()` doesn't exist in 3. At least not by that name, it was renamed to `.items()`.

Comment: You could just use the solution above then.  I prefer to stay away from lists because if the dictionary size is too big, I believe making a new list creates a large list.

Comment: Don't do this sort of thing, *please*. Use something like `2to3` to generate Python 3 version rather than writing awful code.

Comment: +1 for a solution that generates an iterator without any version check of the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Python2.7 has an `.items` method in the dictionary which allows you to iterate over (key,value) tuples. Python3 has the same API (although the implementation is different). Will this work for you?

Comment: but in Python2, `.items()` builds a temporary list which the OP is trying to avoid

Comment: The question is not very clear but i think that the author wants generators. I changed the title of the question to reflect that.

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thanks.